# RC4 OpenSSL adds garbage characters when decrypted

Tags: c++, openssl

when i decrypt file with openssl's rc4 function some part of it, contains garage characters

```
RC4_KEY key;
RC4_set_key(&key, pass.length(), (const unsigned char *) pass.c_str() );
RC4(&key, text.length(), (const unsigned char *)text.c_str(),(unsigned char *)decrypted.c_str());
```

any help ? thanks

Comment: `(unsigned char *)decrypted.c_str()` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: You can't fill a `std::string` using it's `.c_str()`. Casting `decrypted.c_str()` to an `(unsigned char *)` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: So how did you fix it? I'm working on  a similar project and am facing similar difficulties